# Eclipse CLP: maximum number of constraints/variables

Tags: prolog, constraints, eclipse-clp, clp

In the Eclipse CLP, how many constraints or variables can I define?

I am currently remodeling my scheduling problem - I need to replace a single `alldifferent` constraint with many `atmost` constraints. But since I've introduced this change, my ecl script is not working. By "not working" I mean the Eclipse CLP - eclipse.exe or the TkEclipse GUI just shuts down. Without any error message,comment or saying goodbye. Just nothing.

If I try to comment-out some constraints, the script at least gets compiled.

Has someone already bothered with this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to compile huge, generated source files? In that case you could blow the system stack, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific limit on the number or variables or constraints.

But you were working with large, generated source files where clauses had thousands of subgoals.  Because ECLiPSe uses a recursive descent parser, such files can cause an OS stack overflow, in particular on Windows.  You could either [increase the Windows stack limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack), or you could break your generated code into smaller clauses, and call these in conjunction.

Generally, however, generating textual source code isn't such a great idea: it must be created, written, read, parsed, compiled, and is then executed just once.  Consider instead generating a **pure data file** that contains only things like arrays/lists of numbers, but **no variables**.  You can then have a generic ECLiPSe program that reads these data and uses them to create variables and constraints, usually in several loops.

For a very simple example, compare https://eclipseclp.org/examples/transport1.pl.txt (where all the data is explicit in the flat model) with
https://eclipseclp.org/examples/transport_arr.pl.txt where the model is generic and all data comes from the data/3 fact at the end (this would correspond to the generated data file).